# Reader for a MySqLConnection without database parameter in Connection String

Tags: c#, mysql

I'm trying to run the following query via a DataReader on a MySQL instance. The reader always returns null and I understand it is due to the missing Database parameter in the connection string. How do I get this query to work. I need the username, database name and the hostname from the database but I'm not sure which database to query for the same.

```
select current_user(), database(), @@hostname hostname;
```

The call is made in the following function and the connection is not specific to any database:

```
public DatabaseDetails GetDetailsDetails(ConnectionDetails details)
    {
        using (var dbCommand = details.Connection.CreateCommand())
        {
            dbCommand.CommandText = "select current_user(), database(), @@hostname hostname;";
            using (var dr = dbCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.SingleRow))
            {
                return dr.Read()
                    ? new DatabaseDetails
                    {
                        Username = DBFunction.GetString(dr, 0),
                        Database = DBFunction.GetString(dr, 1),
                        Server = DBFunction.GetString(dr, 2)
                    }
                    : null;
            }
        }
    }
```

Connection string used:

```
user id=root;password=***;data source=localhost;integrated security=false;auto enlist=true;
```

Additional information:
I'm not able to get the top 20 records from any database table even when i put the database name within the query. the datareader on debug shows rows but all of them are "?". For example with the following commandtext, i get no records:

```
select * from db_sample.table_sample limit 20;
```

**Update:**
I have worked my way to pull the data from a table when the database is mentioned either in the query or in the connection string. Now I just need to get the following from the mySQL data server without knowing the database (using a query):

- Database Name
- Host Name
- User Name

Comment: Can you share the connection string you are using? you can mask the important details with "*".

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya, added the connection string used. The connection is opening as expected.